# How to reduce the access to an authentication and authorization platform at the server side

Tags: caching, access-token, server-side

I am sending the Access Token in the header to a server (graphQL). The server accesses the authentication and authorization platform (in my case it is Auth0) to get the e-mail of the user from the Access Token and based on it the user profile is set.

How to reduce the access to an authentication and authorization platform at the server side? Is Access Token caching for different users on the server side a valid solution? If yes, how the lifetime must be defined and updated?

Comment: Depending on what you trying to do, you can restrict access based on the role of the user server side, but this question is very ambiguous to begin with.

Comment: But precisely it is not possible to guess the role from the access token without connecting to the platform or having it in cache!